# Xpages: Java method using OpenNTF ODA not saving document

Tags: java, xpages

I have adopted the OpenNTF ODA for java in Xpages. It is really great so far, and I think I have just touched the surface.

I am calling a Java method and want to save a document. The method is getting called, and I am not seeing any errors, but the document is never updated.

The document is getting "saved" but it just disappears from the views.

```
import lotus.domino.NotesException;

import org.openntf.domino.*;
import org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory;
import org.openntf.domino.Database;
import org.openntf.domino.Session;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Build implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void process1(String docID) {

        try {

        System.out.println("Got here.");
        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database thisDB = session.getCurrentDatabase();
        Database PCDataDB = session.getDatabase(thisDB.getServer(), "scoApps\\PC\\PCData.nsf", false);
        Document thisDoc = PCDataDB.getDocumentByUNID(docID);   
        Item itm = thisDoc.replaceItemValue("status",2, true);
        thisDoc.save(true,false);
        System.out.println("Got here.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it print out all the sysout statements? I'm not aware of anything that should cause a problem there. I've not really used the third parameter for replaceItemValue(), but the fact that it disappears suggests that's not throwing an error. Looking at the code, I can't see an error in the code and I've tried with the current ODA in the demo database. It correctly sets as a summary field and the value displays in a column in the view. It may be worth checking org.openntf.0.0.log to double-check there are no errors thrown by ODA itself.

Comment: I've never used the 3rd parameter either, though I doubt that's the problem.  I also don't normally create an "Item itm" object for just writing a value.  If you're not going to do anything with "itm" then you don't need it.  Something else is going on.  Possibly what Rob Mason suggests.  I would also suggest installing the xpages log reader as well.

Comment: It does print out the system statements. I only put in the third parm to see if it made a difference. The odd thing is that when I step through with the debugger, I can see the doc but I am not seeing the fields that I should be seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the document is actually being saved, but there is a value getting set on the document means that is excluded from the view you are looking at.

You can create an All Documents view.  Set the formula to Select @All.  Add a column for Form and one for Last Edited Date, set appropriate sort options and you should be able to find the doc and see why it is being excluded from the view.

Answer (score 0):

This was an oversight on my part. The code was changing the field "status" from 1 to 2, but I when I initially set up the field it was text, not a number. So my document fell out of all views. When I took Rob's advise and looked at All documents it was easy to see what was happening.

Comment: Nice one Bryan.  I only added that answer as I had been in that exact same boat and ended up pulling hair out for ages trying to get to the bottom of it.